# Join multiple tables located in different databases using Informatica

Tags: sql, sql-server, informatica, informatica-powercenter, netezza

I am trying to join 6 tables where 5 tables are located in Netezza database and the last table is present in SQL Server database. I need to join these six tables and extract all the required fields and load them into the target table which is located on Netezza.I tried writing SQL in SQL override to join all the tables but it throws me an error. Can someone help me how to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Joiner transformation`.

First join the 5 tables which are located in the same database. Put this SQL that joins 5 tables in one source qualifier. This will join and extract the data from one database. Next create another source qualifier to extract data from the 6th table.

Finally join the data from these two source qualifiers using a Joiner Transformation and you are done.

Comment: I wont be able to join 5 tables because there is no common key. Table present in other database has the keys.

Comment: In that case you need to extract these 6 tables individually to your staging area and perform the join there

Comment: You have 6 tables in source and you want one table in your output. Problem is, you can't join 6 tables together in a single `source qualifier` as they belong to separate databases. In fact, you can not even join the 5 tables in the same database together as joining needs to happen via the 6th table. I am suggesting you to extract all these 6 tables individually into a single database (e.g. staging area) using one Informatica mapping (having 6 pipelines) and then create another mapping that will join these 6 staging tables together in one SQ, and load them to the target.

Comment: Or use 5 joiners to let Integration Service perform all joins.

Comment: Perhaps (depending on table sizes) a two-phase approach: `first session` to load the SQL Server table to Netezza and then `second session` with single source qualifier and SQL override to perform join fully on Netezza side and read the result.